# Can't load optimizer weights after adding layer without parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

**MODEL A**:

```py
ipt = Input(batch_shape=(32, 240, 4))
x1  = Conv1D(16, 20,  strides=200, padding='same')(ipt)
x1  = BatchNormalization()(x1)
x2  = Conv1D(16, 200, strides=120, padding='same')(ipt)
x2  = BatchNormalization()(x2) # ...
```

**MODEL B**:

```py
ipt = Input(batch_shape=(32, 250, 4))
x1  = Conv1D(16, 20,  strides=200)(ipt)
x1  = BatchNormalization()(x1)
x2  = Conv1D(16, 200, strides=120)(ipt)
x2  = BatchNormalization()(x2) # ...
```

---

The two have identical weight shapes - however, A's optimizer `weights` *cannot* be loaded onto B, as B has a different build order (images & code below).

This is a tiny snippet of a much larger model which needs its `timesteps` parameter changed every X epochs, and `ZeroPadding1D` appears to *change layer build order* whenever it's used; this doesn't affect *model* weights, as they're mapped via a dictionary - whereas optimizer weights are mapped sequentially, list-to-list.

Reproducible in both TF1 & TF2, and w/ `keras` & `tf.keras` imports. What's the problem, and how to fix? [Relevant Git](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34182)

---

**Environment**: Win-10 OS, CUDA 10.0.130, cuDNN 7.6.0, Python 3.7.4, GTX 1070

**Observations**:

- Swaps any other layer, not just `BatchNormalization` - and any *number of layers* before `concatenate`; optimizer weights end up being simply swapped in `.get_weights()`
- Can change `strides` instead of `batch_shape[1]`
- Can use `MaxPooling1D` w/ `strides > 1`
- `padding='valid'` leads to `ZeroPadding1D`, but it *doesn't* change build order (don't know why)

---

**`model_A.summary()`**:

```py
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to     
==================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(32, 240, 4)]       0                            
__________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d (Conv1D)                 (32, 2, 16)          1296        input_1[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)               (32, 2, 16)          12816       input_1[0][0]    
__________________________________________________________________________________
bn_1 (BatchNormalization)       (32, 2, 16)          64          conv1d[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________
bn_2 (BatchNormalization)       (32, 2, 16)          64          conv1d_1[0][0]   
__________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (32, 2, 32)          0           bn_1[0][0]       
                                                                 bn_2[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________
gap_0 (GlobalAveragePooling1D)  (32, 32)             0           concatenate[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (32, 1)              33          gap_0[0][0]
```

**`model_B.summary()`** *(note the swapped layers)*

```py
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(32, 250, 4)]       0                               
_____________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)               (32, 2, 16)          1296        input_2[0][0]       
_____________________________________________________________________________________
bn_1 (BatchNormalization)       (32, 2, 16)          64          conv1d_2[0][0]      
_____________________________________________________________________________________
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)               (32, 3, 16)          12816       input_2[0][0]       
_____________________________________________________________________________________
zero_padding1d (ZeroPadding1D)  (32, 3, 16)          0           bn_1[0][0]          
_____________________________________________________________________________________
bn_2 (BatchNormalization)       (32, 3, 16)          64          conv1d_3[0][0]      
_____________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (32, 3, 32)          0           zero_padding1d[0][0]
                                                                 bn_2[0][0]          
_____________________________________________________________________________________
gap_0 (GlobalAveragePooling1D)  (32, 32)             0           concatenate_1[0][0] 
_____________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (32, 1)              33          gap_0[0][0]
```

---

**Minimally reproducible code**:

```py
# also works with `from keras`
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, ZeroPadding1D, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Dense, GlobalAveragePooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

def make_model(batch_shape):
    ipt = Input(batch_shape=batch_shape)

    x1  = Conv1D(16, 20,  strides=200, padding='same')(ipt)
    x1  = BatchNormalization()(x1)
    x2  = Conv1D(16, 200, strides=120, padding='same')(ipt)
    x2  = BatchNormalization()(x2)

    x1, x2 = zero_pad(x1, x2)
    preout = concatenate([x1, x2])
    preout = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(preout)
    out    = Dense(1)(preout)

    model  = Model(ipt, out)
    model.compile('adam', 'mse')
    return model 

def zero_pad(x1, x2):
    diff = int(x2.shape[1]) - int(x1.shape[1])
    if   diff > 0:
        x1 = ZeroPadding1D((diff, 0))(x1)
    elif diff < 0:
        x2 = ZeroPadding1D((abs(diff), 0))(x2)
    return x1, x2

def make_data(batch_shape):
    return (np.random.randn(*batch_shape), 
            np.random.randint(0, 2, (batch_shape[0], 1)))

batch_shape_A = (32, 240, 4)
batch_shape_B = (32, 250, 4)
batch_shape_C = (32, 240, 4)
model_A  = make_model(batch_shape_A)
model_B  = make_model(batch_shape_B)
model_C  = make_model(batch_shape_C) # 'control group'
x_A, y_A = make_data(batch_shape_A)
x_B, y_B = make_data(batch_shape_B)
x_C, y_C = make_data(batch_shape_C)

model_A.train_on_batch(x_A, y_A)
model_B.train_on_batch(x_B, y_B)
model_C.train_on_batch(x_C, y_C)

optimizer_weights_A = model_A.optimizer.get_weights()

model_C.optimizer.set_weights(optimizer_weights_A)
print("model_C optimizer weights set successfully")

model_B.optimizer.set_weights(optimizer_weights_A)
print("model_B optimizer weights set successfully") # will not print
```

**Output**:

```py
model_C optimizer weights set successfully

ValueError: Optimizer weight shape (16,) not compatible with provided 
weight shape (200, 4, 16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround, and a form of explanation; it isn't about `ZeroPadding1D`, but about there being an additional layer in one 'branch' and not the other - as revealed by `plot_model()`; see below.

Keras appears to build layers via *vertical traversal* - note that the numbered layer graphs match exactly w/ `.summary()` ordering. Order change could still have occurred toward the end of the 'branch' - I suppose the reasoning is, the two branches' layer nodes should be at the same depth before merging to a common layer. *However*, this isn't the full story - see disclaimer at bottom.

**Workaround**: insert a 'pseudolayer' to equalize # of layers in each branch; I'll stick with the z-padding:

```py
def zero_pad(x1, x2):
    diff = int(x2.shape[1]) - int(x1.shape[1])
    if   diff > 0:
        x1 = ZeroPadding1D((diff, 0))(x1)
        x2 = ZeroPadding1D((0, 0))(x2)
    elif diff < 0:
        x2 = ZeroPadding1D((abs(diff), 0))(x2)
        x1 = ZeroPadding1D((0, 0))(x1)
    return x1, x2
```

Running the code in the question:

```py
model_C optimizer weights set successfully
model_B optimizer weights set successfully  # SUCCESS
```

---

**Model graphs**: via `from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model; plot_model(model_A) ...`

[image]

---

**Explanation disclaimer**: I haven't confirmed it in  exact lines of source code, and `.summary()` doesn't always agree w/ `plot_model()`; for example, using `padding='valid'`, we get `model_B` graph above for both `model_A` and `model_B`, yet summary shows `model_A`'s build order. Also, `padding='valid'` works without the fix because both models end up using `ZeroPadding1D`, so the layer structure is (seemingly) identical.